# How can I find out whether to install games to $prefix/bin or $prefix/games?

Tags: shell, unix, portability

I have written [a game](http://github.com/fuzxxl/dobutsu) for UNIX-like operating systems. I am currently writing the installation scripts for this game.

[Traditionally](http://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/7/hier/), game binaries were installed into `$prefix/games`, however some operating systems like FreeBSD have started to get rid of the `games` directory. What is a good way to determine whether to install game binaries into `$prefix/games` or `$prefix/bin` if the user doesn't explicitly specify?

My installation scripts are written in the a common subset of the features provided by ksh93, bash, and the POSIX shell. They should only call into widely available utilities.

For clarification: The topic of this question is not determining `$prefix`. It is determining which of `$prefix/games` and `$prefix/bin` to use if the user doesn't specify a subdirectory explicitly.

Comment: AFAIK, /usr/games is still the place for games in FreeBSD, but it's an optional install -- not everybody wants or needs it. That said, there's prior art for installing things into $prefix/$packagename/, like PostgreSQL going into /usr/local/pgsql in FreeBSD. You're also free to use $prefix/bin for binaries, $prefix/lib for libraries, $prefix/etc for configuration, etc, as long as **the files you add to the system are recorded in the local package management system**. Software that doesn't play nice with packaging will never get installed on systems I maintain. Period.

Comment: Also, I'm afraid this doesn't sound like it's on-topic for SO. I recommend you ask around in IRC channels for the various operating systems you're interested in supporting. It's entirely likely that different platforms will have different preferences.

Comment: @ghoti No, it is not. For example, on my Linux system nethack is installed into `/usr/games/nethack` whereas on FreeBSD the port is patched to install into `/usr/local/bin/nethack` because `games` has been abolished.

Comment: @ghoti I see you voted for close as off-topic. However, I don't see how my question is asking to “recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.” Note also that shell-scripting is generally seen as within the scope of SO. I do not really see your point.

Comment: Check if `/usr/games` exists and if it does, install into `$prefix/games`?

Comment: @GrishaLevit good idea.

Comment: If you have a problem with a shell script, please include the code, I'd be overjoyed to help. As-is, this question appears to be about hierarchy and packaging rather than programming. There is no code to fix here, and "best practice" answers will depend on operating system and opinion. If you have a specific programming question, ask it.

Comment: For FreeBSD, I see that as of FreeBSD 11, tools that were in `/usr/games` like `rot13` and `fortune` have moved into `/usr/bin`. On FBSD, should consider `/usr/games` (if it exists) to be part of the "base" system, and you should not install things into it. Instead, third-party software should always be installed somewhere under `/usr/local`. Everything under `/usr` except `local` is off-limits to third-party software, except in very special (legacy) circumstances.

Comment: @ghoti That's why I specifically wrote `$prefix` everywhere in my question where `$prefix` is the prefix in which to install the software. Nowhere did I say that I consider to use `/usr` as the prefix by default.

Comment: @ghoti The point of my previous remark about `nethack` installing into `/usr/games/nethack` on Linux was to show that the subdirectory `games` in an installation tree is no longer used for any software, not just the base system. That Linux package managers install other software into the `/usr` tree instead of the `/usr/local` tree is not relevant to this observation.

Answer (score 1):

In FreeBSD, third party software is intended to be installed in `/usr/local`.  The `/usr/games` directory, if it exists, shouldn't be touched.

In OS X, software applications are bundled and installed into the `/Applications` folder, but text base game (which I assume this is) probably doesn't make sense there. If you install software using [MacPorts](http://macports.org), it tends to go into `/opt/local`. If you install software using [Brew](http://brew.sh), it tends to go to `/usr/local`, to avoid conflicting with MacPorts. But the "rules" of the hierarchy under `/*/local/` are different from the ones under `/Applications`.

In most Linux distros, software can be installed anywhere, as long as it doesn't conflict with previously installed software. There are guidelines, but less adherence to them as far as I can tell.

The big commonality between all of these is that there's a packaging system involved. You can usually do whatever you like, as long as you keep track of what you're doing in a packing list. (See `port contents {portname}` in macports, `pkg info -l {portname}` in FreeBSD, `dpkg-query -L {pkgname}` in APT-based systems, `rpm -ql {pkgname}` in RPM-based systems, etc.)

My advice would be to keep your install as simple but as flexible as possible, and let the local packaging system enforce its own rules about where things go. Your software shouldn't have to change just because some operating system has decided that games should live in a different place.

Set your prefix as something like `PREFIX?=/usr/local` so it can easily be overwritten by an enclosing script or Makefile. Check out the different variants of the `install` command to determine whether there's a basic set of options that are universal in the platforms you intend to support, and if there aren't, just copy files with `cp`, or include your own `install` script as part of your software.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer, though I do not see how it answers my question at all.

Comment: What he's saying is "don't bother trying to select an install directory based on any criteria - just specify your preference, and permit it to be overwritten easily by those who have different preferences from yours."

Comment: Hmm, yes, exactly. And dang, I didn't expect a downvote for that. :-(

Comment: I have downvoted because you exclusively talk about `$PREFIX` which is not the topic of my question at all. I was asking about how to find out whether to use `$PREFIX/games` or `$PREFIX/bin` if the user doesn't specify otherwise. And you don't answer this question at all.

Comment: @Graham I have added some clarification to the question to explain why I think your post does not answer my question. If I had asked “how do I choose `$PREFIX` in a portable manner?” then your answer would have received an upvote and might have been accepted, but sadly that is not the question I asked.

Comment: @fuz, I thought "**My advice would be to ... let the local packaging system enforce its own rules about where things go**" was pretty clear. I talked about `$PREFIX` because you talked about `$prefix`. Your question is an XY Problem -- "How do I make this decision which is not mine to make". Just install consistently somewhere, and let users or packaging systems override as they deem necessary.

Comment: @Graham I didn't not talk about `$PREFIX` in the sense that my question does not concern at all how to choose `$PREFIX`. What's so hard to understand about that?